# separar 2 carpetas en lua

Tags: lua

Hace días estoy buscando como descomponer una ruta. Estoy en **lua autoplay media studio**.

No se mucho de programación, pero requiero descomponer un directorio. Lo que pude hacer parte de código investigando logre descomponer el driver, los folder archivo y extension, solo que ahora en folder me los dio juntos y deseo separar cada uno alguien me puede ayudar.

```
path_parts = String.SplitPath("C:\\MyFolder 1 \\MyFolder 2 \\edit.exe");
drive =(path_parts.Drive.."");
folder =(path_parts.Folder.."");
```

Ahora solo me quedan asi los folder \folder 1\folder 2\
sigo buscando y solo me falta separar los folder cada uno en una input sin \ he estado parte del dia y hasta ahí me quede

Comment: Bienvenido. Por favor, sigue el [tour] y revisa [ask]. Cuida la gramática y ortografía ya que de otra forma podría resultar imposible entender a qué se refiere tu pregunta. Si no has obtenido respuesta, revisa la redacción de tu pregunta y usa el enlace [edit] para actualizarla; sólo agrega etiquetas que sean relevantes. Por favor, no publiques de nuevo la misma pregunta sobre todo si sólo ha pasado una hora de haber hecho la publicación original.

Comment: Quiero añadir que [String.SplitPath](https://www.indigorose.com/webhelp/tu/Program_Reference/Actions/String.SplitPath.htm) no viene incluida de forma nativa en la biblioteca `String` de Lua [The String Library](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.html), al parecer está dentro de las funciones de [autoplay media studio](https://www.indigorose.com/autoplay-media-studio/), el cual sí emplea Lua como un [Scripting Engine](https://www.indigorose.com/autoplay-media-studio/flexible-lua-scripting-system/)

Answer (score 0):

La solución que se va exponer está acá en [replit](https://repl.it/repls/PlushHandsomePetabyte) para que pueda ser ejecutada.

Empleé y modifiqué parte de esta [biblioteca](https://www.fhug.org.uk/wiki/wiki/doku.php?id=plugins:code_snippets:split_filename_in_to_path_filename_and_extension) para que soporte Unix, porque el post inicial no indica el sistema operativo.

```
local separaNombreArchivo = function(nombreArchivo)
    -- Retorna ruta, nombre de archivo, y extensión como 3 valores
    return string.match(nombreArchivo, "(.-)([^\\/]-%.?([^%.\\/]*))$") -- modificado para que soporte también Unix
end

ruta, archivo, extension = separaNombreArchivo("C:\\MyFolder 1 \\MyFolder 2 \\edit.exe")
print(ruta.."\n"..archivo.."\n"..extension)
--[[
    ---------------------------
    Se Imprime:
    ---------------------------
    C:\MyFolder 1 \MyFolder 2 \
    edit.exe
    exe 
]]
```

Lo siguiente que ya es intrínseco a la consulta pasa por captar los folders, los cuales están entre `"\".... "\"` excepto al inicio del `C:`

Sumado a lo anterior, la ruta contiene espacios en blanco que se deben suprimir:

```
ruta = string.gsub(ruta, "%s+", "")       -- suprimimos los espacios en blanco
local folders = "\\"..ruta                -- cada palabra queda entre '\ \'
local folders = folders:gsub("%\\", "\n") -- reemplazamos '\' por salto de nueva línea '\n'
                                          -- para ver si el procedimiento está funcionando
print(folders)
    --[[
        ---------------------------
        Se Imprime:
        ---------------------------
        C:
        MyFolder1
        MyFolder2
    ]]
```

Después se procede a encontrar los indices en una cadena de texto (el salto de línea, no es un `split` es decir no se ha divido la cadena, sólo se hizo para efectos de impresión)

```
-- Tomado de:
-- https://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html
local t = {}                   
local i = 0
while true do
  i = string.find(folders, "\n", i+1)   -- salta hasta encontrar el nuevo salto de línea "\n"
                                        -- local folders = folders:gsub("%\\", "\n")
                                        -- buscamos el siguiente '\'
  if i == nil then break end
  table.insert(t, i)
end
print(unpack(t)) -- indices de la cadena de texto
--Se imprime: 1 4   14  24
```

Con los indices se puede efectuar un `bucle` for

```
local misFolders = {}
for i=2, #t-1 do -- por que empieza en C:
  misFolders[#misFolders+1] = string.sub(folders, t[i]+1, t[i+1]-1)
end
print(unpack(misFolders))
-- se imprime: MyFolder1    MyFolder2
```

Resumiendo el código quedaría así:

```
local separaNombreArchivo = function(nombreArchivo)
    -- Retorna ruta, nombre de archivo, y extensión como 3 valores
    return string.match(nombreArchivo, "(.-)([^\\/]-%.?([^%.\\/]*))$")
end

ruta, archivo, extension = separaNombreArchivo("C:\\MyFolder 1 \\MyFolder 2 \\edit.exe")

ruta = string.gsub(ruta, "%s+", "")
local folders = "\\"..ruta

local t = {}                   
local i = 0
while true do
  i = string.find(folders, "\\", i+1)   
  if i == nil then break end
  table.insert(t, i)
end

local misFolders = {}
for i=2, #t-1 do -- por que empieza en C:
  misFolders[#misFolders+1] = string.sub(folders, t[i]+1, t[i+1]-1)
end

-- imprimimos todos los datos contenidos en la tabla
print(unpack(misFolders)); print("\n")

-- imprimimos uno por uno las carpetas
for _, v in pairs(misFolders) do print(v) end
```