# Separa carpetas de una cadena

Tags: php, javascript, c++, lua

Buen dia una ayuda hace dias estoy buscando como descomponer una ruta estoy en lua autoplay media studio, no se mucho de programación, pero requiero descomponer un directorio lo que pude hacer parte de codigo investigando logre descomponer el driver, los folder, archivo y extencion, solo que ahora en folder me los dio juntos y deseo separar cada uno alguien me puede ayudar.

```
    path_parts = String.SplitPath("C:\\MyFolder 1 \\MyFolder 2 \\edit.exe");
    drive =(path_parts.Drive.."");
    folder =(path_parts.Folder.."");
    Input.SetText("Input1", driver);
```

Ahora solo me quedan asi los folder \folder 1\folder 2\ sigo buscando y solo me falta separar los folder cada uno en una input sin \ he estado parte del dia y hasta ahí me quede

Comment: de todas la etiquetas que agregaste de los lenguajes utilizados ¿Qué lenguaje es? ¿php, js, c++?

Comment: el titulo tampoco ayuda mucho

Comment: Posible duplicado de [separar 2 carpetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/82238/separar-2-carpetas)

Comment: Sí @Rubén es un duplicado y cuenta con respuesta en este enlace [separar 2 carpetas en Lua](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/82238/separar-2-carpetas-en-lua)